# C# MongoDB.Driver slaveOk()

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way in C# to run slaveOk() or SetSlaveOK() before querying a mongodb database?
I have access only to a secondary replica (backup). It works fine with Robo T3 if I first run rs.slaveOk().
Installed latest version on MongoDb.Driver through nuget, but I can't see this method available.

Thank you,
Radu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var clientSettings = new MongoClientSettings();
clientSettings.ReadPreference = ReadPreference.SecondaryPreferred; // or ReadPreference.Secondary
```

See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference

also, you can use `slaveok=true` option in a connection string